# Discord.js - command line issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("!Bonk")){
        let userToMention = message.mentions.users.first();
        message.channel.send("bonks "+userToMention.toString() + "  https://tenor.com/view/bonk-meme-dog-doge-gif-14889944");
    }

});
```

**What this does is when you run the command `!bonk @devildog` the bot displays a `gif + @devildog`.
But when you run the command `!bonk` alone the bot randomly crashes. Is there any way you can solve this issue with `if else`?**

Error:

```
message.channel.send("bonks "+userToMention.toString() + "https://tenor.com/view/bonk-meme-dog-doge-gif-14889944");
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: I would suspect that if the message contains 0 mentions, the `message.mentions.users` is empty, therefore `userToMention` is null, and you can't call `toString()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your example, the invocation command doesn't include any mentions, the call to `message.mentions.users.first();` will cause a crash. When no users are mentioned (like in your example), the `first()` method won't be able to find the first user in `users`, because there are no users mentioned at all! Thus, calling `toString()` on a `null`/`undefined` object will result in an exception.

Check for users in your initial `if` statement to prevent this behavior:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("!Bonk") && message.mentions.users.array.length > 0){
        let userToMention = message.mentions.users.first();
        message.channel.send("bonks "+userToMention.toString() + "  https://tenor.com/view/bonk-meme-dog-doge-gif-14889944");
    }

});
```

Comment: alright, the crashing problem is solved, but now the bot stopped responding to the command

Comment: You should employ standard JavaScript debugging concepts to determine what about the `message.mentions.users.array.length` expression prevents the main portion of the script from running.

Answer (score 0):

Hello again @Blissy89!

Yes, you can fix it by just using:

```
if(!userToMention) return message.say('Mention a user to run this command!')
```

**Put it ABOVE** `message.channel.send`